# How to export and deploy a JavaFX application with H2 embedded database?

Tags: java, database, maven, javafx, module

I'm working on a Rubiks Cube scramble generator and visualizer project in `java`, `javafx` with `maven`, and i want to export it as a standalone app, and send it to my friend. I use a `H2` embedded database in the project to store the solve times, but with `mvn clean javafx:jlink` i can't do that because the `Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: com.h2database`. Is there any way to export a JavaFX project with a embedded database / automatic modules?